# Multiple linear operations impact on overall function worse case complexity?

Tags: c++, loops, time-complexity

This is perhaps somewhat of a simple question, but I'm going to ask anyway folks:

I've written the below function:

```
std::vector<int> V={1,2,3,4,5};
int myFunction()
{
   for(int i=V.size();i--;){//Do Stuff};
   for int e=V.size();i--;){//Do Stuff};
}
```

This needs to have **time complexity worse case O(n)** and **space complexity of worse case O(1)**.

Does having two linear operations (for-loops) change the time complexity to something other than O(n)?

Comment: No. Not the theoretical asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Note that if `n` is the size of the array, then the sample code has space complexity O(n), rather than O(1).  (If you knew that, I suggest removing the O(1) comment;  if you mean *additional* space complexity, then please [edit] your answer to say that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It does not. `O(N)` means something like `aN+b + something weaker than linear N`.

Even something like: `T(N)= 5N+100 + Log(N)` is considered as `O(N)`.

By "something weaker than linear N", I mean any function R(N) that satisfies the equation:

```
lim R(N)/N = 0 ; N-->Inifinity   //Use L'Hospital's Rule for solving these kind of limits
```

So `O(N)` can be written as:

```
O(N) = aN+b + R(N)
```

---

**Side Note:** Complexity does not equal to Performance. Although `(N+N)` is still `O(N)`, this does not mean it is not slower than `(N)`. Performance, in its most basic form, is about the number cycles you need to do something not about the theoretical complexity.

However, it should be related at least when `N` goes to very big number (almost Infinity).